# typescript and cloud9 ide how to?

Tags: typescript, cloud9-ide

I would like to use typescript language within cloud9 ide.

Do you know, if there are some tutorials to explain how to do ( autocompletion, add d.ts references, compile, debug)?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Cloud9 has NPM support, you can compile your Typescript by installing the 'typescript' package.

1. Go to the console (at the bottom of the IDE) and run `npm install typescript`.

   This installs `tsc`, which can be used to compile your Typescript.
2. Run `tsc /path/to/file.ts` to compile.

Syntax highlighting is provided by the Ace editor.

Comment: also I have tested / use grunt-ts which works fine : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts and can watch your files for changes